# AWS SDK swift com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use the AWS SDK to create an endpoint on an application so that I can send push notifications. The push notifications go through when I manually enter the details on the AWS console but I'm trying to register the device from inside the app so that new users can be signed up.

Following the steps on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/setup.html I have created the credentials for the app in the AppDelegate and use these credentials in another class.

The code I'm using to try and access the AWS SNS is :

```
func subscribeEndpoint(json: JSON)
    {
        let sns = AWSSNS.defaultSNS()

        let request     =   AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput()

        let user_id     =   json["id"].string!
        request.token   =   "XXXXX"
        request.customUserData  =   user_id

        print("token : \(token) user : \(user_id)")

        request.platformApplicationArn = "XXXX"        

        sns.createPlatformEndpoint(request).continueWithBlock({ (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if task.error != nil {
                print("Error dis: \(task.error!)")
            } else {
                let createEndpointResponse = task.result as! AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse
                print("endpointArn: \(createEndpointResponse.endpointArn)")
            }

            return nil
        })
    }
```

I have tested using the device token generated by the device when registering for notifications (this value works when inputting on the AWS SNS console). The user_id has also been tested and isn't null.

The error I keep getting is

```
Error dis: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSNSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

Not really sure what the cause of the problem is but if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an authorization error. Are you setting the default service configuration correctly?

When you use `AWSSNS.defaultSNS()` it loads the configuration from the default configuration object. The credential provider used for the default configuration should assume a role which has permissions to call `createPlatformEndpoint` from the client.

You can verify it from the IAM console if the role that is assumed has enough permissions.

Thanks,
Rohan